# Що означає слово "загаї"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

Натрапила у збірнику "Колядки та щедрівки / Вступ, ст. О. Дея. – Київ: Наук. думка, 1965" у колядці "Ци дома, дома господарейко" на такі рядки  "У тебе лани, як загаї, У тебе хліби, як тихий Дунай". Почала з’ясовувати, що означає слово загаї, але результат не зовсім вдалий.

У **[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=215547&page=943)** є словникова стаття ***загай***, але тут не подають визначення, лише відсилають до слова **загайка**. У цій же статті така ж ситуація: без пояснення відсилають до наступного **затримка**. Аж [тут](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=33253&page=1066) читаю:

> **ЗА́ТРИ́МКА**, и, ж.
>
> 1. Дія за знач. затри́мати.
> 2. Припинення на який-небудь час дії, руху і т. ін.
>
> (1) Без за́три́мки (без за́три́мок),у знач. присл.– не затримуючись, швидко.

Отже, виходять так: "У тебе лани, як затримка", що не може відповідати насправді.

Тож що означає це слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Українському тлумачному словнику](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/50365/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B9) знаходимо:

> **Загай**:
>
> 2) зах. Зарості, нетрі.

Оскільки, попередньо в цій колядці вихваляється велике і багате господарство пана Івана(*«…У тебе худоби без рахуби /У тебе скрині все кованії,/У них червінці не рахованії…*"), то, очевидно, **лани такі густі, як нетрі, зарості**. Тобто, лани, які дадуть великий і плідний урожай.